# How can I add new ArrayList (as field) to realm db

Tags: ios, swift

When i try to add new field ("iconImage") into model and after to realm , i get the error like this "**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value to initialize object of type 'IconImage': missing key 'imgUrl** ". How can I resolve it?

AppDelegate:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(

   schemaVersion: 18,

     migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

        if (oldSchemaVersion < 18) {
             migration.enumerate(Place.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                  newObject!["iconImage"] = List<IconImage>()
                    }
                }

        })
```

My Object:

```
class IconImage: Object {
    dynamic var imgUrl: String = ""
}

class Place: Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var categoryID = 0

    var iconImage = List<IconImage>()
}
```

Add Realm db:

```
func addPlace(id: Int, categoryID: Int, iconImage: List<IconImage>) {

    let place = Place()
    place.id = id
    place.categoryID = categoryID
    place.iconImage = iconImage

    try! self.db?.write {
        self.db?.add(place, update: true)
    }
}
```

set List (my mistake)

```
let iconList = List<IconImage>()
for (_,image) in images {
     let img = IconImage()
     img.imgUrl = image.stringValue
     iconList.append(img)
}
```

Comment: as far as i understood it, you only have to migrate "changes" (change property-name for example). The "new" properties you can simply add to your model

Comment: how can i set imgUrl as you said i have to make changes in property-name?

Comment: Already resolved! The problem was in the set place.Thanx!